# Question about evaluation control

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting

I want to make a function that takes a function as a parameter and prints an integral with the function inside.  I've tried this:

```
L[f_, a_, b_] := HoldForm[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]]

L[E^-Sqrt[#] &, 0, 1]
```

But it gives me this:

$$\int_0^1 \left(e^{-\sqrt{\text{#1}}}\text{&}\right)[x] \, dx$$

I want the integrand to look normal, that's all, so I want the variable x to be substituted inside it, but not evaluated any further.  Is this possible?

Comment: It seems to work if you just remove HoldForm, since it's a delayed set, f is equal to your input function when it evaluates, and since x is only mentioned inside Integrate, there should be no problems.

Comment: @jVincent The OP needs the integral to stay unevaluated, and merely display as an integral.

Comment: My bad, I read through it to fast.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works nicely:

```
L[f_, a_, b_] := HoldForm[Integrate[#, {\[FormalX], a, b}]] &[f[\[FormalX]]]
```

Note that I used [`\[FormalX]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) to prevent conflicts with the usual `x`, which may have had a previous definition. Try `L[E^-Sqrt[#] &, 0, 1]` with this definition:

[image: example]

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need:

```
Block[{Integrate, HoldForm}, L[E^-Sqrt[#] &, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Undergoing succintness training? +1

Comment: @Rojo I wish :)

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to change the displayed form of the expression, you can create a custom `MakeBoxes` call to format it as you want:

```
MakeBoxes[L[f_, a_, b_], StandardForm] ^:= 
RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox["\[Integral]", ToBoxes[a], ToBoxes[b]], 
ToBoxes[f["x"]], RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", "x"}]}]
```

In this way, `L[f,a,b]` will remain an object in computations, but whenever the front-end displays it, it will look like you desired, just like `Power[x,2]` will display like a raised power, but remain the expression if you manipulate it.

Comment: I was looking at that, but the documentation about boxes is confusing and I don't understand it.

Comment: Boxes are the structures used to describe the displayed form of the content in the front-end. I agree that it's difficult to get a grasp of how it all works from the documentation. A nice way to get a feel for what boxes are is to select a cell and use Cell>Show Cell expression (or Shift-ctrl-E), this shows you the box form that is interpreted as the shown expression.

Answer (score 5):

```
fun = E^-Sqrt[#] &;
```

I'd suggest something simpler, like

```
L=Composition[HoldForm, Integrate];
```

So you would do

```
L[fun[x], {x, 0, 1}];
```

and you explicitly choose the integrand. Note that this version won't work if your integrand has a value. For that, look at the other good answers.

Furthermore, if you want the output to be evaluatable, so that if you copy-paste it or reevaluate the output cell you get the actual integral, just replace `HoldForm` with `Defer`

```
L=Composition[Defer, Integrate];
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following:

```
Clear[L]
L[f_, a_, b_] := Block[{x}, With[{expr = f[x]}, HoldForm[Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}]]]]
```

Using `Block` makes sure that this will work even if `x` has a value.  `With` is commonly used for expression injection.

Answer (score 4):

Also it is possible to use `ReplacePart` and `Defer`:

```
L[f_, a_, b_] := ReplacePart[Defer[Integrate[1, {x, a, b}]], {1, 1} -> f[x]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more way. Try:

```
 L[f_, a_, b_] :=
    TraditionalForm[
         Style[Defer@Integrate[f, {x, a, b}], 
               FontFamily -> "Tahoma", 
               FontSize -> 24, Bold
         ]
    ];

L[Exp[x], 0, \[Infinity]]

L[Sin[x], 0, \[Pi]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]