# HoldForm: how does it interact with nested evaluations?

Tags: evaluation

Here's an example to illustrate the issue I'm having.

```
right = 8 - y;
left = y^2 + 6;

integrand = HoldForm[Evaluate[right]] - HoldForm[Evaluate[left]]
```

[image]

(I realize this is a strange form for `integrand` but it is the form I need to work with.) Here, `HoldForm` allows its argument to be evaluated, and then holds the form of the resulting output. This is what I wanted.

Then

```
simpleintegrand = ReleaseHold[integrand]
```

[image]

which is fine.

However,

```
HoldForm[Integrate[Evaluate[simpleintegrand], {y, 0, 1}]]
```

yields

[image]

(removing the `Evaluate` doesn't help) when I was after $$\int_0^1 (2-y-y^2)\,dy.$$

(In another direction, I'd actually prefer to get $$\int_0^1 (-y^2-y+2)\,dy$$ and am happy to hear how, but **the crux of my question is how to use `HoldForm` when its argument involves nested commands like above.**)

Comment: `Integrate[HoldForm[Evaluate@simpleintegrand], {y, 0, 1}]` but I've failed to apply `PolynomialForm[#,TraditionalOrder->True]&` to get the second form.

Comment: The simple answer is that `Evaluate` only works when it is at the first level of a held expression.  Consider:  `Hold[1, Evaluate[2 + 2], 3]` versus `Hold[{1, Evaluate[2 + 2], 3}]` -- in the second case nothing evaluates.  But instead of telling us that this "is the form I need to work with" why don't you tell us what you are trying to *accomplish* and we may be able to give you a different approach.

Comment: Almost the exact same question was already asked. There are million ways to do this and the keyword is *non-standard evaluation*. This is not restricted to `HoldForm`! One possible solution to your first question is `HoldForm[Integrate[#, {y, 0, 1}]]&[Evaluate[simpleintegrand]]`. I'll mark it as duplicate so you'll see the original Q&A.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about evaluation control](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5526/question-about-evaluation-control)

Comment: @halirutan: Before posting, I studied that example. However, it seemed to me that with my example it was the combination of the `Integrate` and the evaluation of the integrand, whereas there was only the former in the linked question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Fair enough... I want to show the set up of integrals in a certain form (e.g., think area between curves, I have a right and left curve, so the initial set up should look like `Integrate[right-left,{y,ymin,ymax}]`. I thought the best way to preserve this particular form of the integrand would be the form I have above. However, this fails for even the simple example `right = 9-y^2;
left = 5; HoldForm[Evaluate[right]] - HoldForm[Evaluate[left]]` and I don't understand why. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at comments such as this:

> For example, `right = 9-y^2; left = 5; HoldForm[Evaluate[right]] - HoldForm[Evaluate[left]]` doesn't preserve the "right minus left" ordering, yet `HoldForm[HoldForm[Evaluate[right]] - HoldForm[Evaluate[left]]]` fails. Ideas?

I think you didn't understand what I said about `Evaluate` so I'll try again.

- `Evaluate` only works when it is the explicit head of an expression at level one.
- You cannot use `Evaluate` in the way you keep attempting: it won't work.

Instead you need to use a different method to control evaluation in your expressions.
Let me direct you to some useful posts on the subject:

[Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/121)

[Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/121)

But here you don't even need these advanced methods, you can do a simple replacement:

```
right = 9 - y^2; left = 5;
HoldForm[r - l] /. {r -> right, l -> left}
```

> ```
> (9-y^2)-5
> ```

Or a `Function`:

```
right = 9 - y^2; left = 5;
HoldForm[# - #2] &[right, left]
```

> ```
> (9-y^2)-5
> ```

---

Kuba criticizes this code if e.g. `left = -5` is used saying that "in general it is not useful."  I disagree.  It outputs exactly what you instructed it to.

```
right = 9 - y^2; left = -5;
HoldForm[# - #2] &[right, left]
```

> ```
> (9-y^2)--5
> ```

You introduce two separate `Times[-1, _]` expressions here; look at the `FullForm`:

```
HoldForm[# - #2] &[right, left] // FullForm
```

> ```
> HoldForm[Plus[Plus[9,Times[-1,Power[y,2]]],Times[-1,-5]]]
> ```

You should use a form that does not if you want proper formatting of `Plus` by `MakeBoxes:

```
HoldForm[+##] &[right, 5]
HoldForm[+##] &[right, -5]
```

> ```
> (9 - y^2) + 5
>
> (9 - y^2) - 5
> ```

See this answer and the ones linked within for more examples:

[How can I reorder the factors in the terms of a polynomial?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30216/how-can-i-reorder-the-factors-in-the-terms-of-a-polynomial/30240#30240)

Comment: The problem is, that in general it is not useful, try: `left = -5;`

Comment: This is helpful, especially the links. Several other methods I tried kept running into the issue Kuba points out here. The $--5$ isn't a problem (for my application) if it would write it as $-(-5)$.

Comment: @Kuba Please see update.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for update. Yes, it looks like I criticized the code but I should have added that that answer was good (+1ed earlier). I know we are getting what we are asking for :). I just wanted to point out this issue which would appear for everyone who was going to play with this code. p.s. - I like those tiny details in your codes, here the **`+`** `##`.

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Thus far, this seems to be doing best what I need across the widest variety of cases: `HoldForm[Subtract[#1, #2]] &[right, left]`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
right = 8 - y; left = y^2 + 6;
integrand = HoldForm[Evaluate[right]] - HoldForm[Evaluate[left]]
```

[image: integrand.png]

```
With[{f = ReleaseHold@integrand}, HoldForm@Integrate[f, {y, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: integral.png]

```
% // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> 7/6
> ```

Comment: This is helpful. I'm still trying to better understand `HoldForm` especially when I want to pass arguments some of which I want evaluated. For example, `right = 9-y^2; left = 5; HoldForm[Evaluate[right]] - HoldForm[Evaluate[left]]` doesn't preserve the "right minus left" ordering, yet `HoldForm[HoldForm[Evaluate[right]] - HoldForm[Evaluate[left]]]` fails. Ideas?

Comment: @JohnD. At this point, I think the best thing I can do is recommend David Wagner's book, which has a good discussion of working with held forms. Go to [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/3066) for info on how to get for free. Also, what you bring up with the ordering of `right = 9 - y^2; left = 5;` has more to do with the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus` than it does with held forms.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in my comment, for your first question please look at the explanations here

[Question about evaluation control](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5526/187)

For your second question about the polynomial ordering, you can use the same approach to create and fix the presentation

```
(* your original code *)
right = 8 - y;
left = y^2 + 6;
integrand = HoldForm[Evaluate[right]] - HoldForm[Evaluate[left]]

(* tweaked presentation *)
Integrate[#, {y, 0, 1}] &[
 HoldForm[Plus[##]] & @@ MonomialList[ReleaseHold[integrand]]]
```

and you get

$$\int_0^1 \left(-y^2-y+2\right) \, dy$$